# Multiple special character occurrence pattern replacement

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a text like bellow where multiple `*` and white spaces are repeated in a pattern.

```
txt = """Passenger requested a physician be paged . Page was answered by * * * * * * in seat 35H. * * spent a great deal of time with patient * * * * checking her vitals and filling out form"""
```

I need to condense the pattern to `* white space * (* *)`

```
required_output = """Passenger requested a physician be paged . Page was answered by * * in seat 35H. * * spent a great deal of time with patient * * checking her vitals and filling out form"""
```

using Python 3 and 'RE' package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex. And you would need to replace the found matches with "* *":

```
(?<=[^\*] )(\* )+\*(?= [^\*])
```

https://regex101.com/r/tHWGT8/3

Use like this

```
re.sub(r'(?<=[^\*] )(\* )+\*(?= [^\*])', '* *', your_string)
```